# How do I fix the React Router 'unexpected token <' error?

Tags: node.js, react-router, reactjs

There is a problem with my react.js / node.js app. I use React-routers in my app, and have very nasty mistake.

[Index route works, everything is fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft1pP.png)
[image]

[Routes like "/something" also work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLi33.png)
[image]

But routes like "/something/something" don't work:

(Next images are in comment to this question)

[When I first loaded this page][3]

[When I reloaded page][4]

My code: 
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Boox</title>
   <meta name="theme-color" content="teal">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./plugins/css/normalize.css" />
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./plugins/css/animate.css" />
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="./plugins/materialize/css/materialize.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">

  </div>
  <script src="./plugins/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src='./plugins/materialize/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'

import App from './App.js';
import Main from './components/Main.js';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound.js';

import Users from './components/user/Users.js';
import Profile from './components/user/Profile.js';
// components
import Signup from './components/user/auth/Signup.js';
import Signin from './components/user/auth/Signin.js';

import Editor from './components/user/write/Editor.js';
import Write from './components/user/write/Write.js';

// styles
require('./less/common.less');



ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Main} />
      <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="signin" component={Signin} />
      <Route path="write" component={Write}>
        <Route path=":id" component={Editor} /> // This doesnot work :(
      </Route>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path=":id" component={Profile} /> // This doesnt work :(
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path=":id" component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Users.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'

export default class Users extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {

    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>TEST USERS ROUTE</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Server.js also contain this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
})
```

I would be glad to any advice. Thanks.

Comment: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qz7R.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLgsD.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8cxZ.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z765B.png
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIRlv.png

Comment: Please do not post code/errors/other text as images. When image links go down, context is lost. Also, no matter what, images can't be searched for text from google for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
All my links were relative `./plugins/css/normalize.css`, and when I tried to load `localhost/write/123`, they (links) were trying to load `localhost/write/plugins/css/normalize.css`.

I have removed dots `/plugins/css/normalize.css` and problem solved!
Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are seeing is related to trying to load a resource like a js script or css script and your express server doesn't handle that route. which then means it returns the html file. and javascript goes ugh I dono what `<` is.. if you notice `<` is the first character in the html file.

To give a complete answer I would need to see what your server file is to see which route is missing. But my guess would be any of these are the culprit

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./plugins/css/normalize.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./plugins/css/animate.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="./plugins/materialize/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="./plugins/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src='./plugins/materialize/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

basically any import that you have that has a local path. You need to make sure you have a route on the server that accepts it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wIRlv.png

My server.js image. Can you tell smth?

Comment: why are you giving me images? and did you not hear anything I said in my answer? you have to accept those routes you are requesting on the server

Comment: It seems that I didn't understand you, sorry. You said "To give a complete answer I would need to see what your server file". Okay, I need to resolve routes `./plugins/css/normalize.css` and others.

Comment: Problem solved. All my links was relative, for example, `./plugins/css/normalize.css`. I have rremoved dot `/plugins/css/normalize.css`, and all works!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is about using relative paths inside react code (very common approach), could be fixed by adding this:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Inside **head** section of your index.html file.